# Memory leak in UIImage's imageWithContentsOfFile

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a table view with 10 cells displaying an image. Everytime I scroll, the app allocates more memory (but doesn't show this in leaks) but in allocations, I can see that memory increases by like 2 megabytes with each scroll.

This is the code which leaks, specifically the line where i set the imageview's image (if I comment it out, it doesn't leak):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"background_stripes" ofType:@"png"]];
    return cell;
}
```

[image]

**UPDATE:** I created a simple new project with 1 view controller:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tableView.rowHeight = 130.f;

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 16;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"background_stripes" ofType:@"png"]];


    return cell;
}
```

Very simple...I don't see any problem here...but leaks when I scroll, the memory consumption grows over time...

Comment: why don't you use imageNamed: ?

Comment: @PaulNadolinskyi Because the real images that I want to use are in documents directory (for whom imageNamed doesn't work). I simply tried an image in my NSBundle to see if it makes a difference (still leaks), but ultimately I will need to use imageWithContentsOfFile.

Comment: is ARC on in your project?

Comment: Looked in the graphs just now =) The top graphics illustrates the allocations not leaks, they are in the bottom graphics and their graph is red, so there is NO memory leaks

Comment: @PaulNadolinskyi Yes, but the total allocated memory keeps increasing. Just because there's no red doesn't necessairly mean there's no leak. I have 16 rows, each time I scroll up/down 1 cycle, I raise app's total mem consumption ny 3 MB. 1 simple view controller, slowly grows from 6 mb to 53 mb. No memory leaks?

Comment: Do you know the difference between Live Bytes and Overall Bytes?

Comment: @PaulNadolinskyi No, but now I do :p - Do you want to leave this as an answer so i can close this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that there is no leaks =). The top graph illustrates the allocations and not leaks. Leaks are in the bottom graphics and their graph is red, so there is NO memory leaks. You'd probably thought that "Overall Bytes" stands for memory leaks but it's not, it's just the number of bytes that program allocated during runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with dataWithContentsOfURL: solved it by @autoreleasepool

Try this:

```
@autoreleasepool {
     self.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"background_stripes" ofType:@"png"]];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't work. I am not using my subclass any more, using the built in UIImageView in UITableViewCell.